# Where can i find high dimensional data with a big sample size?

Tags: data-request

I would like to work with some tabular data to do some regression variable selection where the sample size and dimension (n and p) are both above large. Let's say n>800 and p>8000.

I have seen when p is large, but usually n will be quite small such as ~100.

Comment: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.php is a good place to start